# Is it okay to save 1000 videos of size 200 kb locally in the app,either android or iOS?

Tags: android, ios, performance, memory-management

I have a need to store 1000 of videos locally of sizes not more than 200 kb in document folder and then save name in database, so the user can view them anytime without internet connectivity, my question is this the right approach or should I just tell my client that storing 1000 videos can effect the app performance severely?

Comment: Saving a lot of data locally won't hurt app performance, unless you try loading all the videos at once.

Comment: you expect the user to download an app that holds 200mb of their storage hostage until the uninstall the app?

Comment: make some categories for the videos and give the user the option to manage the storage aka delete / redownload the videos from a server.

Comment: @tyczj I was also thinking that....thanks for your reply